# How to set a Row witch width is 25% at the end of the row?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I did [image: this]

using this code.

```
<div class="row mw-md-100 d-flex w-25 justify-content-end mb-2" >
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <nb-select
      fullWidth
      class="mw-md-100 mb-md-3 mb-2"
      placeholder="User Name"
    >
    </nb-select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**But I need to move this at the end of the row not start of the row.
How can i do?**

**Update: Answer is**

```
<div class="row mw-md-100 d-flex w-100 mb-2 justify-content-end ">
  <div class="w-25 advanced-filters">
  <div class="col-md-12 " >
    <nb-select fullWidth class="mw-md-100 mb-md-3 mb-2" placeholder="User Name" [formControl]="selectedSiteFormControl">
    </nb-select>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

set background color to 2nd div

```
    .advanced-filters {
      background-color: #222b45 !important;
    }
```

Comment: You probably got mixed up with your class, you probably wanted to do something alike `<div class="row mw-md-100 justify-content-end mb-2">
  <div class="col-md-3">` row is already a flex container col-3/col-x-3 equals 25% (3 out of 12) ;) If i understood right your trouble.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it is to leave the row at `100%` width and give the `w-25` to the `col` and then adding the `flex-row-reverse` class to the row.

```
<div class="row mw-md-100 d-flex flex-row-reverse mb-2">
  <div class="col-md-12 w-25">
    <nb-select
      fullWidth
      class="mw-md-100 mb-md-3 mb-2"
      placeholder="User Name"
    >
    </nb-select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just assuming you want  to float on right side

```
<class="row mw-md-100 d-flex w-25 justify-content-end mb-2">
  <div class="col-md-6">something else here</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <nb-select
      fullWidth
      class="mw-md-100 mb-md-3 mb-2"
      placeholder="User Name"
    >
    </nb-select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you could add `float: right` inside `<div class="col-md-12" style="float:right">`